# Controls Accessibilty- Microsoft Azure playground

Tags: html, css, typescript, azure, accessibility

I'm improving a website to be accessibility friendly.
using Microsoft Azure playground, Essentials and Text block controls.
I'm trying to do this with the CSS methods:

```
.class-name {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
```

with no help.
How can I make these controls to respond?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: the css you mention have, in essence, nothing to do with accessibility, maybe share some more code and the exact goal ?

Comment: Hi @Meni, we need some more information to be able to help you. Most accessibility on websites is HTML related so could you post the HTML that you are having a problem with and try and explain what you think is wrong with it and what you are expecting it to do, from there we can offer potential solutions.